# Items missing from Reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I'm simply asking this question out of curiosity about how the site's reputation calculation is supposed to work.  I've never seen anything weird with the rep calculations before today.

It seems like there are items missing from my reputation tab or that perhaps something is being hidden.

About an hour ago I was at 1403 rep and after I submitted a new answer, the page refreshed to show 1398.  Nothing at all is showing where the -5 came from.

Then at the same time somebody up-voted and accepted another answer where it shows +15 and +10.  A few minutes later, there was another +10 up-vote on a different answer.  (+35 total)

It's not showing where the -5 came from and +35 was not added to either 1398 or 1403.

The new rep is now 1423.  A gain of +20 or +25 depending on that missing -5.

I don't believe I'm anywhere near a daily cap.

Shouldn't all items that add/subtract from the rep be shown under that tab?  Again, I don't consider being off a few points a major issue at all. I'm just wondering if/how these observations are logically explainable.

Comment: The missing -5 could be from someone undoing an upvote on a question.

Comment: @Troyen:  I'm not sure... there had been no activity for 6 hours prior.  Wouldn't undoing an up-vote have to occur pretty quick?

Comment: There's a five minute window after the vote, which is reset if you edit.  I'm not aware of any other situations that result in a -5 though, aside from a score 1 question being deleted, but I thought that needed a manual recalc to show up on your score.

Comment: @Troyen:  I know; it's very weird.  Ignoring the -5, I'm missing +15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The accepted answer you got today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511258/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-ie-9-not-working) is not new, OP accepted yesterday, and he unaccepted today and accepted again.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6511258/timeline

And upvote you got today on that post could also be undo, and redo, so probably there is no +35 today.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank-you for explaining it all to me!  I feel stupid for not being able to find that timeline view... where is the link to get to that?

Comment: @Sparky672, that link is not visible at site, but some browser script could help that - http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an

Answer (score 0):

Reputation changes are now accurate, showing *all* changes for your reputation on your profile.  [These changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) will roll out to the rest of the network soon.